# Quick Question - What is the TPM Connector Size?

Tags: connector, motherboard

Anyone know the connector size for the TPM port? I wanna take the 5vSB power from it.
If it helps its a MSI B450+ Tomohawk.

Thanks!

P.S. I have searched but TPM means too many things!

Edit: WHOOOOOPS! Yes I meant TPM instead of TMP!

Comment: You might want to make it clear it's a connector on a PC motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean TPM?  Looks like an Amphenol  iPN FCI 20021321-00014D4LF is the mating connector 1.27mm pitch 2 x 7 with a key.

Pinout is in the Mobo manual, 3 power supply rails available, but standby is not 5V.

Comment: Thank you! Not only did I mean TPM instead of TMP I also means 3vSB power!

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but it looks like a 0.1"(2.54mm) spacing, something that is quite standard on almost everything from raspberry pi(s) to arduinos.  So a pcb mount connector would look like S7074-ND from digikey.